# findByIdAndUpdate sometimes work and other times not

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to update two document in mongoose but I keep getting

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined"

But sometimes it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
const Installateurs = require("../../Models/Installateurs.js");
const Opdrachten = require("../../Models/Opdracht.js");

const verzendOpdrachtNaarInstallateur = (req, response) => {

  Opdrachten.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, req.body).then((result) => {
    const id = result.installateurs[0]._id;

    Installateurs.findById(id).then((res) => {
      res.opdrachten.push(result._id);
      res.huidigeOpdracht.push(result._id);

      console.log(res);

      Installateurs.findByIdAndUpdate(id, res, { new: true })
        .then((updatedInstal) => {
          response.json(updatedInstal);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
  });
};

module.exports = verzendOpdrachtNaarInstallateur;
```

Comment: Some of your objects have an empty `installateurs` array

Answer (score 0):

not sure but i think its because you have not handled error.
Try this

```
const Installateurs = require("../../Models/Installateurs.js");
const Opdrachten = require("../../Models/Opdracht.js");

const verzendOpdrachtNaarInstallateur = (req, response) => {

  Opdrachten.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, req.body).then((result) => {
    const id = result.installateurs[0]._id;

    Installateurs.findById(id).then((res) => {
      res.opdrachten.push(result._id);
      res.huidigeOpdracht.push(result._id);

      console.log(res);

      Installateurs.findByIdAndUpdate(id, res, { new: true })
        .then((updatedInstal) => {
          response.json(updatedInstal);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
  }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

module.exports = verzendOpdrachtNaarInstallateur;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because "result" and "result.installateurs[0]" are undefined for certain "Opdrachten" ids. Would have been better if you could mention the line number for error as well.
The code snippet although shows some shortcomings that are causing the issue.

```js
const Installateurs = require("../../Models/Installateurs.js");
const Opdrachten = require("../../Models/Opdracht.js");

const verzendOpdrachtNaarInstallateur = (req, response) => {
  // make sure here that the req.body is parsed and contains "_id"
  Opdrachten.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, req.body).then((result) => {
    // handle result == null or other cases here
    if (result && result.installateurs && result.installateurs.length && result.installateurs[0]._id) {
      const id = result.installateurs[0]._id;

      Installateurs.findById(id).then((res) => {
        res.opdrachten.push(result._id);
        res.huidigeOpdracht.push(result._id);

        console.log(res);

        Installateurs.findByIdAndUpdate(id, res, {
            new: true
          })
          .then((updatedInstal) => {
            response.json(updatedInstal);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      });
    }

  }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

module.exports = verzendOpdrachtNaarInstallateur;
```

BONUS : try using async/await to [avoid callback hell](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-avoid-callback-hell-in-node-js/) or promises.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can tell from the code, Looks like:

Either Your
`Opdrachten.findByIdAndUpdate` is not returning `result.installateurs`  property

or

Your `Installateurs.findById` is returning `undefined`.

As much as I can tell from the context for the code.